# Setting an initial value in RadComboBox while using Load on Demand

Tags: telerik, radcombobox, telerik-combobox

My combo is empty until I click the dropdown (items request event is fire): so what is the best strategy to set an initial item (value and text) in RadComboBox while using Loading on Demand?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be sure your EnableLoadOnDemand is set to "true". If it is false (perhaps missing?) it will look like your drop down is empty till you click on the bottom of an empty search box. Below is a bit of code that might help.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Category" runat="server" Width="175px" Height="150px"
    EmptyMessage="Select a Category" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="true"
    EnableVirtualScrolling="true" >
    <WebServiceSettings Method="GetCategory" Path="GetCategory.asmx" />
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```